# what is difference between these two functions in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have two functions. both are working

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$http" ,function($scope,$http) {

}]);
```

and

```
    app.controller("MainController", function($scope,$http) {

});
```

Which one is best to use. and what is the difference in between these.

Thanks

Comment: Its in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). 1) explicit dependency annotation 2) implicit dependency. There has to be lot of duplicates to this question

Comment: also minsafe declaration - preserve paramater names

Comment: Well you do really need to use it if you are using ng-annotate. It will still be minification safe.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose is for minification but there are other uses too

When the second controller is minified it will be

```
app.controller("MainController", function(o,t) {

});
```

Now angular doesn't know what o,t services are...  Of course if you choose to use this you can choose to not mangle your variables during minification.

With the first approach, minification will not change the string values

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope","$http" ,function(o,t) {

}]);
```

Something else which is great with the second approach is that you can name it whatever you like when using the services. For example you might have a really long service called "dataStorageService"

```
app.controller("MainController", ["dataStorageService","$scope" ,function(dss,$scope) {
    dss.smallCodes();
}]);
```

so instead of using dataStorageService.smallCodes(); you can use dss.smallCodes() which is fantastic, this means you can name your services with meaningful words without worrying about it getting too long.

Comment: Well if i am doing minification anyways i would atleast be more readable.. `dataStorageService` or `dataStorageSvc` would be much better than `dss`. Just saying.  :)